# mySQL specifc number of the result

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a function to get the speciic number of the mySQL result. I am using a `while` function.

```
$querycheckmain = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Main`='".$main."'";

$result=mysql_query($querycheckmain) or die("Errore check main: ".mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

`$count` gives me the TOTAL results. What I want is to `echo` the specific number of the result during the mysql `while`.

So if we have 3 results, in order:

```
Mainaccount Paul = result number 1
Mainaccount George = result number 2
Mainaccount Clare = result number 3
```

Is this possible?

I do not need the total result, I need the number of the specific result given during the mysql while.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Didn't get fully what you were trying to get at, but possibly you want to iterate over all values using mysql_fetch_row().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query($querycheckmain) or die("Errore check main: ".mysql_error());

$rowNumber = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rowNumber++;

    // do what you want to do with the $row data here
    // $rowNumber contains the row number

}
```

Comment: So let me understand. You say I can simply echo  $rowNumber++;
and it will give me the specific result? is that right?

Comment: Ok guys THANK YOU. I solved the problem. James C gave me the correct answer. THANKS AGAIN!